# Using JavaScript files in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am learning NativeScript. As part of that, I'm trying out a basic project. In that project, I'm trying to use a JavaScript file that I use for string manipulation. This file does NOT require access to browser elements like the DOM. Yet, I can't run my app when I include the file. At this time, I have the following in my ./app/home/index.js file:

```
var MyFile = require('../app/code/myFile.js');
...
var prefix = myFile.GetPrefix(someStringValue);
```

For more background:

1. I've included the file in ./app/code/myFile.js.
2. I've referenced the file as shown above

Here is what myFile.js looks like:

```
function MyClass() {}
module.exports = MyClass;
MyClass.test = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
};
```

How can I use some existing JavaScript in a NativeScript app?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean when say you can't run your app? Do you get any specific errors? What exactly does `myFile.js` do? You may not access the DOM but you may be relying on `window` or some other globals that aren't present.

Comment: Does your myFile.js properly export its variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an **instance** of *MyClass* in **index.js**. You can instantiate *MyClass* either in:

1. **index.js**:

   var myFileModule = require('../app/code/myFile.js');

   var myFile = new myFileModule.MyClass();

OR...

2. **myFile.js**:

   module.exports = new MyClass();

:: Note that if you do #2 above, in your code...

```
var MyFile = require('../app/code/myFile.js');
```

... the **MyFile variable already IS an instance of MyClass**.

:: A small, unrelated suggestion on coding style: It's better to name your variable(s) **myFile** instead of **MyFile** (note the first lowercase letter in myFile)...