# Simple Diaglog Alert Not Working

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm using Nativescript with javascript and I'm trying to make a button do something when I tap it.

I have a file called login.xml:

```
<Page loaded="loaded">
    <FlexboxLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Test" tap="login" />
        </StackLayout>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</Page>
```

and in my login.js file

```
var dialogsModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/dialogs");

exports.login = function () {
    dialogsModule.alert("test");
};
```

This should make an alert show when I press the button, but nothing happens. If I put this code into the Nativescript playground website it actually works fine (as long as I remove the tns-core-modules part of the require), so I'm not sure if there is something setup incorrectly on my end. There's no errors and I am using the correct location for the dialogs import (although the docs actually say you don't even need it so I tried with just `alert("test");` and that didn't work either.

I don't believe any of my js file code is running even though they are named properly and should be loaded together.

Currently testing with the iOS simulator.

I understand this might be hard for someone to replicate, but maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by just making a new project and adding the code back. Something must have been messed up with the project settings I guess.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to do it like that

this from the Nativescript documentation. [Nativescript documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/dialogs#alert)

```
var dialogs = require("ui/dialogs");
dialogs.alert("Your message").then(function() {
    console.log("Dialog closed!");
});
```

add the .then

Comment: No change when adding .then

Comment: the function is called and the alert is not working ?? or the function not call at all ?

Comment: youre dialog require is different  then the one in the documentation , try to change it

Comment: It seems that my js file isn't working at all, so it not connecting for some reason even though it's named correctly

Comment: try read that 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482486/using-javascript-files-in-nativescript

Comment: Something like that shouldn't be necessary since the xml file will load with the js file of the same name.